# how can i arrange the output of my data i am using group concat?

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

i want to arrange the output of my data in descending Here is my code:

```
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT grade1.Semester, curriculum.SCode, curriculum.SDesc, curriculum.Lec, curriculum.Lab, curriculum.Units, curriculum.Prereq, GROUP_CONCAT(grade1.Grade1) as Grade1 , students.StudNo, grade1.YearLevel
FROM students 
    INNER JOIN grade1 
        ON students.StudNo = grade1.G1StudNo 
    INNER JOIN curriculum
        ON curriculum.SCode = grade1.G1SCode
         WHERE StudNo = '$id'
GROUP BY StudNo,SCode ")
```

Here is the output:
[image].

What i want to happen is 5,5,1.. how can i do that when i am using group_concat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the docs on [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
GROUP_CONCAT(grade1.Grade1 ORDER BY grade1.Grade1 DESC)
```

Comment: it worked! sorry i got clumsy, i change the wrong code.. thx for the help!

Comment: @PiDO: Ha!  It happens to all of us.  Glad to hear you got it working!